# Faced with article that cannot GET

Tags: mediawiki-api

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=extracts&explaintext&format=json&origin=*&pageids=1338305 ([article link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privacy_policy))
returns

```
{
  "batchcomplete": "",
  "warnings": {
    "extracts": {
      "*": "\"exlimit\" was too large for a whole article extracts request, lowered to 1."
    }
  },
  "query": {
    "pages": {
      "1338305": {
        "pageid": 1338305,
        "ns": 0,
        "title": "Privacy policy",
        "extract": ""
      }
    }
  }
}
```

`extract` is empty.

But the same API call for another usual article
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=extracts&explaintext&format=json&origin=*&pageids=7712095 ([article link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_Technology_Act,_2000))
 returns usual correct response:

```
{
  "batchcomplete": "",
  "warnings": {
    "extracts": {
      "*": "\"exlimit\" was too large for a whole article extracts request, lowered to 1."
    }
  },
  "query": {
    "pages": {
      "7712095": {
        "pageid": 7712095,
        "ns": 0,
        "title": "Information Technology Act, 2000",
        "extract": "The Information Technology Act, 2000 (also known as ITA-2000, or the IT Act) is an Act of the Indian Parliament (No 21 of 2000) notified on 17 October 2000. It is the primary law in India dealing with cybercrime and electronic commerce. It is based on the United Nations Model Law on Electronic Commerce 1996 (UNCITRAL Model) recommended by the General Assembly of United Nations by a resolution dated 30 January 1997.\n\n\n== Background ==\nThe bill was passed in the budget session of 2000 and signed by President K. R. Narayanan on 9 May 2000. The bill was finalised  by group of officials headed by then Minister of... full text here.
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like fixed by their side - now GET returns the article.